# SQL Server: calculate whether two columns are matching in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a stored procedure that uses the following lines in order to fetch data from two columns in a table.

Is there a way that in addition to the below I can compare both columns and calculate this as a percentage ?

What I am looking for is one number that says (in %) for how much of the selected records the data in col1 and col2 match, e.g. saying "60%".

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      col1,
                col2
    FROM        LogTable
    FOR XML PATH('archive'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Do you mean for each row, determine if `col1 = col2`, and then a percentage for the whole thing?

Comment: Thanks. No, I meant a total only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likelly contain errors, haven't tested it.

```
declare @i int;
set @i = 0;
declare @t table
(
int id identity,
varchar(max) col1,
varchar(max) col2
)

insert into @t(col1,col2)
select col1,
            col2 from  FROM        LogTable
FOR XML PATH('archive'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks');

set i = 0;
declare @sum int
set @sum = 0;
while(i < select count(*) from @t)
begin 
 select case when (col1 == col2) then @sum = @sum+1 else @sum from @t
where id = i;
i++;
end

print @sum / select count(*) from @t
```

or something in between those lines, do not have SQL Management studio to test atm.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out and respond back.